# Vice Versa query in sql query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

How to block users vice versa in application level through write sql query. Actually my requirement is I block one user in my application I can't see her profile in my timeline and as well as(at the same time) blocked person also can't access(See) my profile in her timeline. Here I write one query and it's working one side means I can't see her profile in my timeline working fine, but I want both sides(vice versa) and I'm passing only User_Id in my web service. I'm passing user_id only in my web service. any one please resolve my issue. And in my table there columns only

```
Block_Id, user_id, Block_user_id.
```

I'm passing `user_id` only

This is my one side working SQL query

```
WHERE audMst.user_id NOT IN (SELECT Block_user_id 
                             FROM tbl_UserBlockMaster 
                             WHERE user_id = @user_id)
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you should explicitly check the reverse condition, i.e. logically something like this:

```
WHERE audMst.user_id NOT IN (SELECT Block_user_id 
                             FROM tbl_UserBlockMaster 
                             WHERE user_id = @user_id)
  AND audMst.user_id NOT IN (SELECT user_id 
                             FROM tbl_UserBlockMaster 
                             WHERE Block_user_id = @user_id)
```

Although I would probably rewrite the entire WHERE clause like this:

```
WHERE NOT EXISTS
  (
    SELECT user_id, Block_user_id
    FROM tbl_UserBlockMaster
    INTERSECT
    (
    SELECT audMst.user_id, @user_id
    UNION ALL
    SELECT @user_id, audMst.user_id
    )
  )
```